# Cannot get network/internet access within crosvm managed VM

Tags: internet, vm

I am trying to run a VM with internet access on my Pixel 6a and Android 14. I am using crosvm to successfully boot debian on the Pixel, but unfortunately I am not able to get internet access (or any communication to the host).

```
# https://crosvm.dev/book/devices/net.html
ip tuntap add mode tap user $USER vnet_hdr crosvm_tap
ip addr add 192.168.10.1/24 dev crosvm_tap
ip link set crosvm_tap up

#routing
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
HOST_DEV=$(ip route get 8.8.8.8 | awk -- '{printf $5}')
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o "${HOST_DEV}" -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i "${HOST_DEV}" -o crosvm_tap -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i crosvm_tap -o "${HOST_DEV}" -j ACCEPT

cd /apex/com.android.virt/bin/

./crosvm run \
    -s /data/local/tmp/crosvm.sock \
    --disable-sandbox \
    --rwroot "/data/local/tmp/debian.ext4"  \
    --net tap-name=crosvm_tap \
    --mem 2048 \
    /data/local/tmp/kernel
```

So far, I followed the crosvm documentation and set up the TAP device and configure networking within the guest as described here: https://crosvm.dev/book/devices/net.html

I am using a kernel that supports virtio, but lspci still shows an unclassified ethernet controller and there is no /dev/virtio-ports device.

```
root@box:~# lspci -k
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 440FX - 82441FX PMC [Natoma]
lspci: Unable to load libkmod resources: error -2
00:01.0 Mass storage controller: Red Hat, Inc. Virtio 1.0 block device (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Red Hat, Inc. Virtio 1.0 block device
    Kernel driver in use: virtio-pci
00:02.0 Unclassified device [00ff]: Red Hat, Inc. Virtio 1.0 RNG (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Red Hat, Inc. Virtio 1.0 RNG
    Kernel driver in use: virtio-pci
00:03.0 Unclassified device [00ff]: Red Hat, Inc. Virtio 1.0 memory balloon (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Red Hat, Inc. Virtio 1.0 memory balloon
    Kernel driver in use: virtio-pci
00:04.0 Unclassified device [00ff]: Red Hat, Inc. Virtio 1.0 network device (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Red Hat, Inc. Virtio 1.0 network device
    Kernel driver in use: virtio-pci
00:05.0 USB controller: Fresco Logic Device 1400
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
00:06.0 Unassigned class [ffff]: Red Hat, Inc. Device 0011 (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Device 00ff:00ff
    Kernel driver in use: pvpanic-pci
```

How to setup a virtual network device on Android properly so that I can get internet/network access within my VM?